# accepts_nested_attributes_for rails 4 is not deleting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been reading and researching for about 3 days now.
This is my last resort.

land.rb:

```
has_many :uploads , :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :uploads, :allow_destroy => true,:reject_if => :all_blank
```

upload.rb

```
belongs_to :land
```

_land_form_partial.html.erb

```
<%= form_for land , :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>

    <%= f.fields_for :uploads do |builder| %>
        <div class="land_fields">
            <%= builder.label :filename, "Image" %>
            <%= builder.text_field :filename %>   <br/>
            Delete: <%= builder.check_box :_destroy %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
 #... buttons and other fields
<% end %>
```

lands_controller.rb

```
def update
    if @land.update_attributes(land_params)
      flash[:success] = "Land updated"
      redirect_to lands_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = @land.errors.full_messages.first
      redirect_to edit_land_path
    end
  end

 def land_params  
    params.require(:land).permit( uploads_attributes: [ :id, :filename ]  )
  end
```

When I add something to the text field and update it, all updates properly. If I click on the check-box it won't remove the field.

Can someone please shed a light on this?

Also I tried [awesome_nested_fields](https://github.com/lailsonbm/awesome_nested_fields) still everything works except for removing the actual record.

thank you in advance.

EDIT: Solution: (I like to put the solution in the question in case someone wants to view it on mobile as I hate when I can't see the solution straight away)

Thanks to @nTraum

```
def land_params  
    params.require(:land).permit( uploads_attributes: [ :id, :filename, :_destroy ]  )
end
```

And all will be dandy :)

Comment: I had the same problem but in my case I was omitting the :id field. Then, if you want to delete a nested model, you need to permit :id and :_detroy attributes of the nested model.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You need to allow the `:_destroy` parameter for your nested model as well, as this gets used when you check the 'Delete' checkbox in the form. It's Rails' way of flagging model instances that have to be destroyed.

```
def land_params  
  params.require(:land).permit(uploads_attributes: [:id, :filename, :_destroy])
end
```

Comment: I think it is cheesy if I say that I LOVE YOU MAN. That was bloody it. Thanks again :).

Comment: Just a note both the :id and :_destroy params are needed, I found that out after only adding the :destory

Answer (score 19):

The OP didn't have the same problem as me, but for anyone coming across this question, for me, it was the absence of `allow_destroy: true` as an argument on the `accepts_nested_attributes` call in the model.

Comment: this should be highlighted in the documentation better