# Rails Destroy All Nested Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations, has-many

I have the following scenario

```
   class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
   
     has_many :depots, inverse_of: :company, :dependent => :destroy
     has_many :users, inverse_of: :company, :dependent => :destroy
     has_many :products
   
   end

   class Depot < ActiveRecord::Base
    
     has_many :products, :dependent => :destroy
     has_many :zones, :dependent => :destroy
     belongs_to :company
   
    end

   class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
     
       belongs_to :depot
       belongs_to :company

    end

    class Zone < ActiveRecord::Base
       belongs_to :depot
    end

    
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :company, , inverse_of: :users
    end
   
   ## and zone has_many locations which further has some associated models.
```

I want to delete all the associated models with company without calling them one by one.
My dependant destroy is not working and when I try to delete the company, products are still there. I have tried replacing

```
  dependent: :destroy #to delete_all
```

but no luck. How can I delete all the nested objects with a single call of destroy to company?

## Edit

I can call

```
 Company.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many)
```

and delete all the associations one by one but I dont want to go for this approach. Any help??

Comment: Please, post the result of the following MySQL query: "SHOW CREATE TABLE companies"

Comment: sorry to mention, I am using Postgres as my DB.

Answer (score 0):

I believe using the "inverse_of" clause in your models is the problem as per the last point in the rails docs on it.  Remove them and give it a try.  As listed in the docs:

There are a few limitations to inverse_of support:

They do not work with :through associations.
They do not work with :polymorphic associations.
They do not work with :as associations.
**For belongs_to associations, has_many inverse associations are ignored.

Comment: it didn't make any difference. I have tried both, with and without inverse_of and it didn't work. I have to use it because I have some associations which need to be preloaded in the form for company. I cant use delete_all because it wont trigger destroy for depots and products.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what is not working with your setup, but it works if you make your `inverse_of` symmetric:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :depots, inverse_of: :company, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, inverse_of: :company, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :products
end

class Depot < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, inverse_of: :depot, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :zones, inverse_of: :depot, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :company, inverse_of: :depots
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :depot, inverse_of: :products
  belongs_to :company
end

class Zone < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :depot, inverse_of: :zones
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company, inverse_of: :users
end
```

**Original answer**

You may want to revise how classes are associated.

In your example the `Depot` class is missing `belongs_to :company`.

Likewise Product's `belongs_to :company` has no counterpart in `Company`.
The latter association may be removed, and transformed into a `has_many through`, as Depots belong to Company and Products belong to Depot.

Answer (score 0):

Are you following the Rails way, so that the `depots` table in your DB has a `company_id` field and so on?

Comment: yes I am, everything is set up properly and I can create depots and products in nested attributes. It means the associations are working fine.

Comment: With the available information I can't figure it out. could you provide the exact code you're using?

Comment: For instance, it may be a controller issue if you're using [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117959/accepts-nested-attributes-for-rails-4-is-not-deleting)